# How to repair corrupted fat32 sd card superblock

Tags: mount, data-recovery, sd-card

I have important data on an external sd card. I plugged in the card and I get an error message. It is a 32GB micro SD card. it was formatted as fat32.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/sam/32GB: 
Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/sam/32GB"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

I absolutely can not lose this data. I am running Xubuntu 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while preparing to boot my raspberry pi. Therefore, I copied the Image- file (raspbian) via `dd` command on the SD- Card. However, I forgot one significant detail: Before using the above mentioned command I did not unmount the directory I wrote the files to (i. e. the directory of the SD- Card), so there was still a mount-point to the SD- directory while writing the image-file via `dd` command. As a consequence I received the same error-message when I tried opening the files on the SD- Card. Maybe the FAT32- partition is broken and your data is lost. Sorry to say, but I had to format my SD- Card, write the image file to the SD- Card again (before I did that I unmounted the directory to which I wrote) and as a consequence I could access the data and it worked out well. If you have any further questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Mount without that all mount options. Plain and simple `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sam/32GB`. Then take a look to your dmesg, if mount is unsuccessful.

Comment: I tried to mount like that. No luck that way. I get the error, mount point /media/sam/32GB does not exist. I was not familiar with dmesg, so after a quick google, I now have this by usin, grep -i usb; https://db.tt/qzOpVRj7  file was too long to paste in.

Answer (score 0):

***Make this an comment rather than an answer***

Sam have you tried `sudo mkdir /media/sam/32GB` first, then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sam/32GB`?

If that does not mount, try `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sam/32GB`

Comment: So, having tried this, it seems a little better than before. I now receive the error message of; "mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock"

Comment: After that, do dmesg in terminal and upload results to pastebin.com, do not post here. You have to put here only link to results. See more https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eJjemn4e those are my results from dmesg. Just want to say thanks to all of you so far for the exceptional help. I really hope we can get this resolved